# JMockit - two mocked instances of the same type

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, jmockit

I'm using the JMockit framework and I'm trying to test my simple `EventBus` implementation which allows `EventHandlers` to be registered for `Event` types. When an event is `fired` on the event bus, all registered handlers get notified. An event can be *consumed* by an event handler which will cause that subsequent handlers will NOT be notified of the event.

My test method looks like this:

```
// The parameter secondHandler should be mocked automatically by passing it
// as an argument to the test method
@Test
public void testConsumeEvent(final EventHandler<TestEvent> secondHandler)
{
    // create the event which will be fired and which the handlers are
    // listening to
    final TestEvent event = new TestEvent();

    // this handler will be called once and will consume the event
    final EventHandler<TestEvent> firstHandler = 
        new MockUp<EventHandler<TestEvent>>()
        {
            @Mock(invocations = 1)
            void handleEvent(Event e)
            {
                assertEquals(event, e);
                e.consume();
            }
    }.getMockInstance();

    // register the handlers and fire the event
    eventBus.addHandler(TestEvent.class, firstHandler);
    eventBus.addHandler(TestEvent.class, secondHandler);
    eventBus.fireEvent(event);

    new Verifications()
    {
        {
            // verify that the second handler was NOT notified because
            // the event was consumed by the first handler
            onInstance(secondHandler).handleEvent(event);
            times = 0;
        }
    };
}
```

When I try to run this code I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at this 
point; please make sure such invocations appear only after the declaration
of a suitable mock field or parameter
```

The exception occurs on the line `times = 0` and I don't know why since the type `secondHandler` should be mocked because it's passed as a parameter to the test method. Adding `@Mocked` or `@Injectable` to the parameter makes no difference.

If I make a standard class from the `firstHandler`, which will just consume the event, and then test the code, everything runs just fine. But in that case I can't verify explicitly that the `firstHandler`'s method `handleEvent` is called because it's not a mocked type anymore.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution of the problem myself. The fix was rather simple, I just needed to transform the `Verifications` block into an `Expectations` block and put it BEFORE the initialization of the mocked `firstHandler`.

It seems to me that the statement `new MockUp<EventHandler<TestEvent>>()` mocks every type of `EventHandler<TestEvent>` and overrides already defined instances, i.e. my `secondHandler`. Whether I'm correct or not or whether it's a bug or a feature I don't know.

If someone knows what exactly is going on, please comment on this answer. Thanks!

Comment: In your original test, the `EventHandler` class was mocked twice, first with the Expectations API (as the "secondHandler" parameter), and then again with the Annotations API (the `MockUp` class instantiation). The second mocking overwrote the first mocking. These two mocking APIs can be used together, but not for mocking the same types in the same test.